# Angular's ngIf showing else template before evaluating condition

Tags: angular, templates, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm checking if there are any elements in array before showing them. If there aren't, a "not available" message should be displayed.

Class:

```
public lists = [];
public isLoading: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getLists()
}

getLists() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.list.getShoppingLists().subscribe(data => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.lists = data.data;
  });
}
```

Template:

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading" class="mx-auto"></mat-spinner>

<div *ngIf="lists.length > 0; then withLists else withoutLists"></div>

<ng-template #withLists>
  <div *ngFor="let list of lists">
      <p>{{list.title}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #withoutLists>
 <p>No lists available</p>
</ng-template>
```

The problem I have is that "not available" message shows in template whilst data is being returned from the API and it shouldn't. Any ideas why this is happening and how should I address this issue?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your if clause is based on the length of the `lists` array which is given an initial value of an empty array.

Updating the logic to include `isLoading` would help for this specific scenario.

`<div *ngIf="isLoading || lists.length > 0; then withLists else withoutLists"></div>`

As per the comments below, a better approach might be to do something more like:

```
<ng-component *ngIf="!isLoading">
   <div *ngIf="lists.length > 0; then withLists else withoutLists"></div>
</ng-component>
```

This way, the intent of the code would be more clear. If it is still loading, don't show anything. Else show the diff with the if/else logic based on the length of lists.

Comment: If I came across this source code. I would be confused as to why the developer wants to display the list while it's still loading.

Comment: I agree. I think it would be better to do something more explicit, but this wasn't a question on code style, but rather why something was working(or not). I'll try to update my answer to include something with a preferred stylistic approach.

Comment: Maybe something like `<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading; else loaded"><mat-spinner class="mx-auto"></ng-container>` where `loaded` is another template, but I agree this is all just semantics on code style.

Answer (score 0):

the callback in subscribe is asynchonous, that means the list is empty while the data is loading, therefore you need to wait for the completion of the loading.
you can solve this either by making:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading || lists.length > 0; then withLists else withoutLists"></div>
```

or wrapping everything like this :

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading">
    <div *ngIf="lists.length > 0; then withLists else withoutLists"></div>

    <ng-template #withLists>
        <div *ngFor="let list of lists">
            <p>{{list.title}}</p>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #withoutLists>
        <p>No lists available</p>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```